# How can I find which chipset the Airport wireless card on my MBP uses?

Tags: network, wifi, hardware

I'm trying to figure out whether my wireless chipset is capable of entering monitoring mode for passive network scanning or packet injection. How can I view the specific chipset information about the wireless card in my macbook pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which chipset you currently have installed in your Mac with the following command:

```
$ system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | grep Firmware
```

You should get a response similar to the following:

```
Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.178.1a2)
```

This tells us we've got the [Broadcom BCM43xx series](https://bcm-specs.sipsolutions.net/Chipsets/).

Comment: How do I know *which* Broadcom chipset exactly? Beyond just `xx`?

Comment: You might have to look that up if you don’t get the specific chip,  this is what the firmware *reports*

Answer (score 0):

Install [AirTool](https://www.adriangranados.com/apps/airtool) and you can capture packets on one channel or all channels.

Apple’s OEM chipsets are quite capable of packet capture and scanning.

Comment: It's great to know that this tool exists!